# Template cross inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm using some code made from other people when I found this:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
    public:   
    Singleton       ( void );
    ~   Singleton       ( );

   ...
};


class Manager: public Singleton<Manager> {

public:
    Manager();
    ~Manager();
...
}
```

I'm aware of the diamond problem, and this reminds me of it.
Is there something that I should check in order to avoid leakage?
The destructors call could create some problem?

Comment: I don't see any "diamond" hierarchy. Your are just prototyping the "singleton" class .

Comment: actually the singleton class it's not just a prototype (here I've just posted some line) but is largely reused in the code without inheritance. 
what concern me is that B inherit from A<B>, could this create some problem?

Comment: Your `Singleton` destructor is not virtual. If polymorphism is used your code could have memory leaks

Comment: "what concern me is that B inherit from A<B>, could this create some problem?" That is a widely used C++ idiom called "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" (CRTP). Google it ;)

Comment: @KeillЯandor believe me, I didn't find the right words to use in order to google it! :) thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do not think destructor call will create any problem. `~Manager` will call the `~singleton<Manager>`. singleton must be having pointer to the unique instance of `Manager` which should be set de-initialed to `nullptr` in `~singleton<Manager>` at the time of destroying only `Manager` instance. So that if some one who tries to access single instance of the `Manager` after that, will get newer instance after earlier Manager instance is freed.